Sugar on Motzei Shabbos
I have heard of a Minhag of the Baal Shem Tov and have observed this amongst Chasidim, to have some sugar in a hot drink on Motzei Shabbos.
Does anyone know the source of this Minhag?

Many have this minhag every single morning

In הליכות קדוש p. 434 R. A.Y.Y. Geldzahler writes (regarding the Rebbe of the Shomrei Emunim):

אחר סדר הלימוד היה רביה"ק זיע"א שותה כוס תה או קפה חם ואמר חמין
במוצאי שבת מלוגמא היא
After his scheduled study the Rebbe would drink a cup of hot tea or
coffee and say "hot water after the Sabbath is a remedy" (Shabboth
119b)

The footnotes add that he would instruct others to add more sugar than during the week and would tell over a story about R. Elimelekh of Lizhensk. King David once appeared to R. Elimelekh after Shabboth and asked him "why aren't you eating a se'udath melaweh malka" R. Elimelekh responded that it was very difficult for him, to which King David responded "at least drink a cup of tea" and when R. Elimelekh drank the tea with sugar then King David would appear to him with a crown on his head, and when he drank it without sugar he would appear to him without a crown. The footnotes also cites another variant of this story according to which R. Elimelekh was accustomed to drinking a cup of tea with sugar on Mosei Shabboth and one time he couldn't find even a bit of sugar in the house to put in his tea, King David appeared to him without a crown and R. Elimelekh asked him "where is your crown?" to which King David responded "where is the sugar that is missing from your Mosei Shabboth tea?"
